# Create a desktop icon to invoke text editor for a specified file

Tags: 17.10, gedit, shortcuts, .desktop, text-editor

I'm [still a complete noob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416513/basic-question-on-setting-higher-screen-resolution) as regards Unix/Linux/Ubuntu. Per that earlier question, I tried installing Ubuntu 4 years ago, but gave up when I couldn't even manage to configure my screen resolution.

I now have a new PC that came with Ubuntu 16.4 LTS pre-installed, and which I successfully updated to 17.10 by following instructions I found online. I'm sure I'll have lots of really basic questions over the coming months as I try to get to grips with it, but I have one particular problem already where I can't find any help online for what looks like a trivial issue.

---

I have a Dropbox file **/home/mini/Dropbox/Public/notes.txt** that I also view/edit from other (Windows-based) machines. Currently I can only access this file by navigating to it using the Ubuntu "file explorer" (Nautilus?).

The only file/icon on my desktop at the moment is something that I *think* is called **Chromium Web Browser.Desktop**, which appeared after I followed online instructions to install that as my default browser. What I want is another file/icon that will invoke **Gedit** on my **notes.txt** file.

I can invoke **Gedit** on the **Chromium...desktop** file, but I don't understand any of the contents, so I've no idea if it's even meaningful to treat that as a starting point for creating my own "shortcut".

On my Windows machines, I can just right-click on a "target" file and select **Send to -> Desktop (create shortcut)** to create an ***.lnk** file, or I can create an ***.bat** file containing the command line **notepad \Users\Fumblefingers\Dropbox\Public\notes.txt**, but I just can't figure out how to do something similar in Ubuntu.

---

To repeat - all I want is a desktop file/icon to invoke **Gedit** on my **notes.txt** file. I still find it hard to believe I can't figure this out for myself, but I'm sure someone here can explain things (in *really simple* terms please! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new file and name it for example gedit-note.desktop in your desktop folder, then write the following inside

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gedit-notes
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit %U /home/mini/Dropbox/Public/notes.txt
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=accessories-text-editor
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
```

This should open gedit with your specific file

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to ***Trust** and launch* the first time I clicked on the file I copied your text into, but now it just does exactly what I'd expect when I double-click on it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you are a relativelly new askubuntu user. Please do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @Bruni: Ooops! I've been around on [SO English Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers?tab=profile) for years, so I should know better! Answer "accepted" now, and thanks for the reminder (I don't suppose there's any point in waiting for a "better" one! :)

Comment: ;-) Maybe I should have bothered to look at the profile.

Comment: @Adel (or anyone else): I don't suppose you could point me to documentation for what all those lines mean. And are they all *necessary?* it seems like a lot of detail for such a simple job.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you can read the article from gnome developer, you'll find what's required for a desktop file to actually work. There is also a description of each line... [https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en#ex-sample-desktop-file]

Comment: @Adel - very useful link, thanks. I'm starting to realise that many of the "standards" I need to get to grips with aren't necessarily part of Linux (or even Ubuntu). In this case it hadn't even occurred to me that I should approach my problem by reading up on the Gnome "desktop environment". Apparently, in this area, Gnome uses / is based on [freedesktop](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) standards, which I'd never heard of until now. But in future I'll know where to look (I'll just come here and follow my own link in this comment! :)